# Spring JPA insert entity with id equals null (should be auto generated)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring's JpaRepository throws an exception when I try to `save` entity without id:

```
MyConfig config = new MyConfig();
config.setValue("value");
myConfigRepository.save(config);
```

*How to make Hibernate not include `id` field into insert query?*

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "MY_CONFIG_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into my_config (value, id) values (?, ?) [23502-190]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:305)
    at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:749)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:78)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:253)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:345)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my entity:

```
@Entity
public class MyConfig {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "MY_CONFIG_SEQ", name = "MyConfSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MyConfSeq")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String value;

    //getters & setters
```

and repository:

```
public interface MyConfigRepository extends JpaRepository<MyConfig, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {}
```

Comment: I can't see the column `MY_CONFIG_ID` mapped anywhere, are you sure it's not just an extra (unmapped) column with a `not null` constraint?

Comment: Just add a `@Column(name="MY_CONFIG_ID")` annotation to `id` field

Comment: simple looking at your DB schema would tell you all you need to know, aka debugging

Answer (score 2):

The column `MY_CONFIG_ID` is not part of your `Hibernate` mapping.

The query for insert inserts into the fields `id` and `value`. Then, there must be a third column named `MY_CONFIG_ID`, which is not mentioned in the `entity`, and thus will be inserted as `null`. If this column then has a `not null` constraint, it will fail.

If you want your `id`-column to be named `MY_CONFIG_ID` then you need to ovveride the default column name (`id`, same as the variable) by annotating it with `@Column(name="MY_CONFIG_ID")`, if you want to use the default name `id` you would need to remove the column (or at least the not null constraint.)